# Problem with shortcode and Ajax in Wordpress

Tags: php, html, ajax, wordpress, shortcode

I'm trying to use shortcodes in WordPress but they don't work after ajax call (when I click on another page of the site, ajax takes another file, for example `file.php` and replaces the central section of the landing page with it).
The problem is that when the page is loaded, shortcodes are printed as they are inserted in the code. For example, I have `[instafeed]` that should show my Instagram feed, but instead the only thing that is printed is `"[instafeed]"`. This also happens with `[bloginfo key='template_url']` shortcode (I took the code from css-tricks).

I've already tried some solutions shown here, but they don't work. For example, I used the code for "bloginfo" that takes the path of the theme folder

```
//StackOverflow solution from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26069355/call-wordpress-shortcode-with-ajax
add_action( 'init', function() {
  ps_register_shortcode_ajax( 'digwp_bloginfo_shortcode', 
'digwp_bloginfo_shortcode' );
} );

function ps_register_shortcode_ajax( $callable, $action ) {

  if ( empty( $_POST['action'] ) || $_POST['action'] != $action )
    return;

  call_user_func( $callable );
}
//End of StackOverflow solution

//Code from https://css-tricks.com/snippets/wordpress/bloginfo-shortcode/
function digwp_bloginfo_shortcode( $atts ) {
  extract(shortcode_atts(array(
       'key' => '',
   ), $atts));
   return get_bloginfo($key);
}

add_shortcode('bloginfo', 'digwp_bloginfo_shortcode');
```

I expect that the output is `path_of_directory_of_theme/` but instead is 
`[bloginfo key='template_url']`

Comment: This might help => https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/227003/shortcodes-not-resolved-in-ajax-call-response, or this => https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/53309/why-might-a-plugins-do-shortcode-not-work-in-an-ajax-request. I know it's feasible, as I know I have got it working before, I just cannot remember how.

Comment: I already tried these solutions but nothing change, it could also be that I put them in the wrong place (at the end of the functions.php file)