Uploading custom wordpress webpage
I am trying to upload a custom webpage but when I go to the URL all I get is 404 page not found. This is what I am currently working with. I have it in the main file path under a checkin folder.
I have also tried adding the webpage to the wordpress theme and adding in the php under function but that didn't work. Any help would be appreciated.
<!DOCTYPE html>
<?php
session_start();
if( class_exists( 'ReduxFrameworkPlugin' ) ) { 
    get_header('pages');
}
else {
    get_header();
}

$url="*****";

$filePath = $_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]."/checkin/";


$err="";
?>

<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<title>Check-In</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
  <h1>Check-In</h1>
  <form id="checkInForm">
    <label for="cardNumberCheckIn">Card Number:</label>
    <input type="text" id="cardNumberCheckIn" name="cardNumberCheckIn" required>
    
    <button type="submit">Check-In</button>
  </form>
  
  <div id="userInfo" style="display: none;">
    <p>Name: <span id="userName"></span></p>
    <p>Email: <span id="userEmail"></span></p>
    <p>Expiration Date: <span id="userExpiration"></span></p>
    <p>Check-In Count: <span id="userCheckInCount"></span></p>
  </div>
</div>
 <?php
// Database configuration
$host = 'localhost';
$username = '*****';
$password = '*****';
$database = '******';

// Create connection
$connection = new mysqli($host, $username, $password, $database);

// Check connection
if ($connection->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $connection->connect_error);
}
echo "Successfully connected to the database.";

// Check if the request is a POST request
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST') {
    // Get the JSON POST body and decode it
    $json = file_get_contents('php://input');
    $data = json_decode($json);

    if (isset($data->cardNumber)) {
        $cardNumber = $connection->real_escape_string($data->cardNumber);
        
        // Update check in count
        $updateQuery = "UPDATE users_table SET check_in_count = check_in_count + 1 WHERE card_number = ?";
        $stmt = $connection->prepare($updateQuery);
        $stmt->bind_param("s", $cardNumber);
        $stmt->execute();

        // Fetch user details
        $selectQuery = "SELECT card_number, name, address, email, expiration_date, check_in_count FROM users_table WHERE card_number = ?";
        $stmt = $connection->prepare($selectQuery);
        $stmt->bind_param("s", $cardNumber);
        $stmt->execute();
        $result = $stmt->get_result();
        
        if ($result->num_rows === 0) {
            http_response_code(404);
            echo json_encode(array("message" => "User not found."));
        } else {
            // Send user details
            $userData = $result->fetch_assoc();
            echo json_encode($userData);
        }
    } else {
        http_response_code(400);
        echo json_encode(array("message" => "Card number is required."));
    }
    
    $stmt->close();
} else {
    http_response_code(405);
    echo json_encode(array("message" => "Only POST method is accepted."));
}

$connection->close();
?>
   
    
<script>
    document.getElementById('checkInForm').onsubmit = function(event) {
    event.preventDefault(); // Prevent the form from submitting the traditional way

    var cardNumber = document.getElementById('cardNumber').value;

    // Make a POST request to the server
    fetch('checkin.php', { // Point this to the PHP script
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({ cardNumber: cardNumber })
    })
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(data => {
        // Display the user information
        document.getElementById('userInfo').style.display = 'block';
        document.getElementById('displayCardNumber').textContent = data.card_number || 'N/A';
        document.getElementById('displayName').textContent = data.name || 'N/A';
        document.getElementById('displayAddress').textContent = data.address || 'N/A';
        document.getElementById('displayEmail').textContent = data.email || 'N/A';
        document.getElementById('displayExpirationDate').textContent = data.expiration_date || 'N/A';
        document.getElementById('displayCheckInCount').textContent = data.check_in_count || 'N/A';
    })
    .catch(error => console.error('Error:', error));
};
</script>
</body>
</html>
<?php if( class_exists( 'ReduxFrameworkPlugin' ) ) { 
    get_footer('v1');
}
else {
    get_footer();
} ?>


Please explain the folder you are uploading to, the method that you are uploading with (ftp, etc.) as well as the URL you are trying

I’m uploading to the public folder, through the file manager in the cpanel. Aceitcanada.com/check-in/

When you say “public folder”, do you mean the root folder of the WordPress site where files such as “wp-config.php” live? And are you creating a folder in this root folder called “check-in”, and uploading files into that? Have you registered these files with WordPress in anyway? Unless you follow WordPress file naming patterns or register your files with WordPress, WordPress does not exist from the PHP perspective. You could also manually “boot” WordPress from your PHP, but I don’t really recommend doing that except for exceptional scenarios.

Yes that’s exactly what I mean. How would I register it with Wordpress?

I would argue that the easiest way is to just create a shortcode that renders your HTML, CSS and JS, then a user can put it on any WordPress page, and the page’s shell will be handled by the template. You can listen for POST requests in the init hook (I think) or maybe parse_request. https://stackoverflow.com/a/26069545/231316. There’s also an official AJAX hook you can be using, too.

The more complicated way is to use rewrites and template_include to register custom routes where you can control everything.

I decided to add a subdomain and add it that way but I am getting a 403 error, do you see any issues with the code for doing it that way?
